# Recommended book for marketing survey design?

Tags: sampling, references, experiment-design, survey

Could someone recommend book for survey design?
I would like to propose good designs for people I am working with. They are trying to conduct survey without control, which is bad design.

So, I am looking for survey / design book. By the way I already know what are type I error, power, confidence interval, CLT, etc. I am already familier with math stat.
Instead, I am searching case study books.

Thank you for your recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "case studies" in this case, but if you're looking for good discussions of survey design rather than the mathematics of it, Groves et al. (2004) *Survey Methodology* is a very practical textbook. It describes several real-life examples of large surveys and illustrates lessons with the National Assessment of Education Progress (NAEP) throughout.

I recently downloaded de Leeuw, Hox and Dillman (2008) *International Handbook of Survey Methodology*. I haven't read much of it yet, so I can't vouch for it, but it seems to me also to focus more on the discussion of concepts than of mathematics, so I'll throw it in here as a suggestion. Plus, it's available [online](http://joophox.net/papers/SurveyHandbookCRC.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! I am very appreciated and will read the Hox and Dillman.